# Explanation of the generalized SWAP test: the permutation test?

Tags: entanglement, fidelity, swap-test

I am reading [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.5788.pdf) paper on the state separability problem, and came across the term “Permutation Test.” This is on page 7 section 2.3.

Apparently, the more famous SWAP test is a special case of permutation test; but I’ve never heard of it.

The steps are below:

1. Prepare a quantum state with $ceil(nlogn)$ qubits (the paper said $n!$ dimensional, which is $O(nlogn)$. Call this state $W$
2. Perform a quantum Fourier transform on this state
3. “Apply a controlled-permutation unitary that permutes registers A1,...,An according to the permutation indexed in register W.” (From the paper directly, a step I don’t really understand)
4. Perform an inverse Quantum Fourier Transform on $W$

How does this test work? I can’t find it on Google; does it go by a different name?

[image: Image of the paper directly]

Here is an image of the paper for reference.